# ESO Authentication on IIS for PHP and .NET applications (Shibboleth / SAML / WiF ...)

Tags: php, asp.net, authentication, iis, single-sign-on

I just wondered if you could answer a question regarding authentication in an enterprise's intranet. We are currently setting up a server for intranet publishing which of course needs protection via an enterprise single sign on.

Unfortunately we are stuck with an IIS server as we need to run both PHP and .NET applications. The main app is programmed in PHP, but we have to feature some jQuery included widgets that rely on ASPX handlers.

The company offers all types of authentication. We've already successfully protected the server with Shibboleth (using SAML 2.0). It shows the ESO screen to login and then redirects to our server with a logged-in session. Unfortunately the widgets that are referring to the ASPX handlers don't authenticate correctly.

I've never done authentication / SAML / WiF / anything, so please excuse my question:

What would be the most promising way for authentication with our setup (IIS featuren PHP and ASPX apps)? Should we stick to SAML and Shibboleth or should we use WiF / WS Federation / Windows Authentication?

Is it possible to support both PHP and ASPX with one authentication method?

Thanks for a response!
Nik

Comment: Doesn't the company prefer an authentication method? It may depend on the scale of the company, but in any setting really I'd expect some kind of policy towards consolidating on a single technology, especially for something as central and critical as enterprise authentication.

Comment: As the company is operating globally they depend on many different authentication techniques. For me it was surprising that the authentication technique depends on the programming languages used. Would it be possible to use Windows Authentication / WiF together with PHP applications?

Comment: It is certainly possible, I personally have excellent experiences with Windows Authentication for PHP applications. We're also using php_ldap to get user details and group memberships out of the AD, so it integrates quite seamlessly in my opinion. Windows Authentication may not be a good fit for public networks, but if the intranet is limited to the local networks / accessed via VPNs / RDP, it may work out well for your scenario too.

Comment: @Fasermaler is it possible to pass Shibboleth's Auth-Token to the Windows Authentication? At the moment only PHP receives the auth token but not the ASPX handlers. Did you use Shibboleth for Authentication or just regular Windows Authentication?

Comment: @praszyk I'm sorry, I don't know since we don't use Shibboleth. We're just using plain old Windows Authentication to authenticate domain users. It seems weird to me though that PHP would receive something that ASPX doesn't. Couldn't it simply be a configuration issue with IIS or some ASPX security setting? Perhaps if you could provide more details on this specific problem in your question, someone might be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about single sign in but check [The DOTNET class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php)

The DOTNET class allows you to instantiate a class from a .Net assembly and call its methods and access its properties.

$obj = new DOTNET("assembly", "classname")

So you can keep authentication @ single library of DOT NET to support both PHP and ASPX with one authentication method.

```
<?php
 $stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
 $stack->Push(".Net");
 $stack->Push("Hello ");
 echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
?>
```

See also [Best way to call .NET classes from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692281/best-way-to-call-net-classes-from-php)